# Issue related to Submit HTTPPOST ActionMethod in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-5

I have asp.net MVC Web application.

i have an input button:

```
<input type="submit" name="Report" value="To File" id="rptToFile" />
```

i have another input textbox :

```
<input type="text" id="txtMemItem1"  name="" />
```

when user hits enter in `TextBox` i have written code to open a new popup:

but problem is: by hitting enter, it calls HTTPPOST Action Method in Controller.. i dont want to submit it on EnterPress key, but want to open popup..

how can i solve my problem ???

THanks

Answer (score 1):

That is default behavior of the HTML forms Whenever focused on form control and you pressed enter form gets posted to the server.

Alternative solution to this behavior can be write a javascript `onkeypress` event and check if `keyCode is 13` (`enter`) then `return false` and open a popup else `return true`.

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" onKeyPress="keyPressed(event)" .../>
```

**Javascript**

```
function keyPressed(event)
{
   var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
   if(code == 13)
   {
       //open a popup here.
       return false;
   }
   return true;
}
```

---

Alternatively if you don't need to post the form ever then you can use something like below too.

```
<form onsubmit="return false" ></form>
```